# Validate Request Body variables through Swagger and Express

Tags: node.js, express, swagger

I am currently using Swagger (2.0) on Node.js. My YAML file validates correctly and the requests are going through. My particular call has a request body using the following format -

```
{
  "postalCode": "invalidpostalcode",
  "phone": "invalidnumber",
  "website": "invalidwebsite"
}
```

I would like to validate each body variable before continuing to the next piece of code. To accomplish validating the data I would like to use [validator.js](https://github.com/chriso/validator.js).

Now my basic validation code looks something like that -

```
  if(!validator.isURL(req.body.website)){
    var tmp  = {
      "message": req.__('error.url', {
          field: req.body.website
      })
    }
    res.status(400).json(tmp);
    return;

  }
  if(!validator.isPostalCode(req.body.postalCode,'any')){
    var tmp  = {
      "message": req.__('error.postalCode', {
          field: req.body.postalCode
      })
    }
    res.status(400).json(tmp);
    return;
  }
```

Is there there any better way to validate data sent in through the API that would require less code? For example by using a function to control the majority of the logic?

while this is one example of the endpoint I will have some in the future that will require upwards of 20 body parameters.

I have tried create a function that will return the response code. However, that returns an error `Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client.`